# How can I prove that a metric defined on two metrics is a metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

In this case, I have the following

> $$d((x_1,y_1), (x_2, y_2)) :=[d_X(x_1,y_1)^2+d_Y(x_2,y_2)^2]^\frac{1}{2}$$

I already proved the first three properties, or so I think, but I'm not sure how to the fourth (triangle inequaity). I know that it works out using Minkowski's inequality, but I don't know how to apply it.

Comment: What is the forth property? Number and enumeration of the axioms depend on the specific definition of a metric, and there are many (equivalent) variants.

Comment: What's the relation between $x, x_1, x_2? $

Comment: @User1865345, $x=(x_1,x_2)$. Obviously.

Comment: @PaulFrost: I assume it is the triangle inequaity, as all other properties are trivial to prove.

Comment: Re fourth axiom, most books define metric space in terms of three axioms.

Comment: @TonyK I agree, but the reader should not be in a position to make a guess. The author should include all relevant information.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thanks for the clarification, I've already made the changes.

Comment: Are you sure you have it right? I would expect $d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2$ inside the square root.

Comment: I was also of the same impression what TonyK is suspecting. If that is so, it's simple application of Cauchy Schwarz. Sutherland's book, for instance (many books, in fact), does explain that.

Answer (score 0):

We are going to prove the following property:

> If $\;\left(X,d_X\right),\;\left(Y,d_Y\right)\;$ are two metric spaces and if $\;d:\left(X\!\times\!Y\right)\times\left(X\!\times\!Y\right)\to\mathbb R\;$ is defined as
>
> $d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}$
>
> for any $\;\left(x_1,y_1\right),\;\left(x_2,y_2\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;,$
>
> then $\;\left(X\!\times\!Y,d\right)\;$ is a metric space too.

**Proof :**

We have to prove that

$1)\;\;d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)\geqslant0\quad\forall\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;;$

$2)\;\;d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=0\;\iff\;\left(x_1,y_1\right)=\left(x_2,y_2\right)\;;$

$3)\;\;d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=d\big((x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_1)\big)\\\quad\;\forall\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;;$

$4)\;\;d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)\leqslant d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)\big)+d\big((x_3,y_3),(x_2,y_2)\big)\\\quad\;\forall\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right),\left(x_3,y_3\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;.$

Now, we will prove $\,1)\;.$

For any $\;\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;,\;$ it results that

$d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}\geqslant0\;.$

Now, we will prove the implication $\,2)\!\!\implies.$

Since $\;d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=0\;,\;$ it follows that

$d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2=0\;,$

$d_X(x_1,x_2)=0\;$ and $\;d_Y(y_1,y_2)=0\;,\quad$ hence ,

$x_1=x_2\;$ and $\;y_1=y_2\;,\quad$ consequently ,

$\left(x_1,y_1\right)=\left(x_2,y_2\right)\,.$

Now, we will prove the implication $\,2)\!\!\ \Longleftarrow\;.$

Since $\;\left(x_1,y_1\right)=\left(x_2,y_2\right)\;,\;$ it follows that

$x_1=x_2\;$ and $\;y_1=y_2\;,\quad$ consequently ,

$d_X(x_1,x_2)=0\;$ and $\;d_Y(y_1,y_2)=0\;,\quad$ hence ,

$d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}=0\,.$

Now, we will prove $\,3)\;.$

For any $\;\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;,\;$ it results that

$\begin{align}
d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)&=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}=\\
&=\sqrt{d_X(x_2,x_1)^2+d_Y(y_2,y_1)^2}=\\
&=d\big((x_2,y_2),(x_1,y_1)\big)\,.
\end{align}$

Finally, we will prove $\,4)\;.$

For any $\;\left(x_1,y_1\right),\left(x_2,y_2\right),\left(x_3,y_3\right)\in X\!\times\!Y\;,\;$ it results that

$d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^2}\leqslant$

$\leqslant\sqrt{\left[d_X(x_1,x_3)+d_X(x_3,x_2)\right]^2+\left[d_Y(y_1,y_3)+d_Y(y_3,y_2)\right]^2}=$

$=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2+d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2+2\left[d_X(x_1,x_3)d_X(x_3,x_2)+d_Y(y_1,y_3)d_Y(y_3,y_2)\right]}\leqslant$

$\leqslant\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2+d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2+2\sqrt{\left[d_X(x_1,x_3)d_X(x_3,x_2)+d_Y(y_1,y_3)d_Y(y_3,y_2)\right]^2+\left[d_X(x_1,x_3)d_Y(y_3,y_2)-d_X(x_3,x_2)d_Y(y_1,y_3)\right]^2}}=$

$=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2+d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2+2\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2+d_X(x_1,x_3)^2d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2+d_X(x_3,x_2)^2d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2}}=$

$=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2+d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2+2\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2}\sqrt{d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2}}=$

$=\sqrt{\left[\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2}+\sqrt{d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2}\,\right]^2}=$

$=\sqrt{d_X(x_1,x_3)^2+d_Y(y_1,y_3)^2}+\sqrt{d_X(x_3,x_2)^2+d_Y(y_3,y_2)^2}=$

$=d\big((x_1,y_1),(x_3,y_3)\big)+d\big((x_3,y_3),(x_2,y_2)\big)\,.$

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$d\big((x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2)\big)=\left\|\begin{pmatrix}d_X(x_1,x_2)\\d_Y(y_1,y_2)\end{pmatrix}\right\|_{\,2}\;,$$

where $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes Euclidean norm.

The triangle inequality of $d$ then follows from

- the triangle inequalities of $d_X$, $d_Y$.
- the monotonicity of $\|\cdot\|_2$, i.e. if $|u_i|\leq |v_i|$ for all $i$, then $\|u\|_2\leq \|v\|_2\;$.

Comment: Triangle inequality of $\|\cdot \|_2$ is not necessary to prove the triangle inequality of $d$.

Comment: Thank you very much for correcting your answer.